# Adjoint representation of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group. 
The adjoint representation $\text{Ad}:G \rightarrow \text{GL}(T_e G)$is given by
$$
\text{Ad}(x):=T_e \mathcal{C}_x,
$$
where $\mathcal{C}_x(y)=xyx^{-1}$.

Now suppose that $G=\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.
Then I would think that
$$
T_e \mathcal{C}_x (y) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} x(e+t y)x^{-1} = \mathcal{C}_x(y).
$$
Is this correct. If this is so, for which Lie groups can't I do this?

Comment: Well, for one, since $y\in\mathfrak{g}$, not in $G$, "$C_x(y) = xyx^{-1}$" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: if the group is realized as a subgroup $G \subset GL(n)$ then you can identify $T_eG \subset T_eGL(n) \equiv GL(n)$. Under such identification you will have $Ad(x)(y)=xyx^{-1}$

Comment: But why is this true, and not for a general Lie group?

Comment: for a general lie group the formula $Ad(x)(y)=xyx^{-1}$ does not make sense because you can not multiply elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $G$. It is possible in this case due to the identification $T_e(GL(n)) \equiv GL(n)$